# ng-bind not working on ng-dialog in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field with the following content

```
<textarea id="textfield" ng-bind="emojiMessage.rawhtml | colonToCode"></textarea>
```

It works very well if I remove it from ng-dialog but when I put it on a ng-dialog it fails. Please what could be wrong or is there better approach that I am missing?

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="firstDialogId">
    <textarea id="textfield" ng-bind="emojiMessage.rawhtml | colonToCode"></textarea>
    </script>
```

=======EDITTED========
This is my controller

```
.config(['ngDialogProvider', function (ngDialogProvider) {
            ngDialogProvider.setDefaults({
                className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                closeByDocument: false
            });
}])
.controller('DialogCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, ngDialog, $timeout) {

            $scope.open = function () {
                ngDialog.open({ template: 'firstDialogId' });
            };

            $rootScope.$on('ngDialog.setPadding', function (event, padding)
            {
                angular.element( document.querySelector('.paddingHeader') ).css('padding-right', padding + 'px');
});
})
```

========This controller defines emojiMessage.rawhtml

```
.controller('emojiController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.emojiMessage={};
```

Comment: Where is your controller?  My guess is ng-dialog is not part of your controller...

Comment: Where is the controller that contains your emojiMessage.rawhtml?  I do not see where that is being defined.  Regardless, the firstDialogId template is not part of the DialogCtrl.

Comment: That is your problem,  the emojiMessage is in an entirely different Scope.  Secondly why are you calling the open from within the DialogCtrl, you'd be better off calling it within your emojiController, and passing your emojiController scope to it.  If the emoji controller is something that is being used in more than one spot, it probably should be in a factory by the way.

Comment: Please post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your emojiController was not within the scope of the dialog.  Move the ngDialog logic to your emojiController, and set scope: $scope.  This should now include the scope of the emojiController.

```
$scope.emojiMessage={};

$scope.open = function () {
                ngDialog.open(
                      { template: 'firstDialogId',
                        scope: $scope
                      }
                );
     };
```

I've added a plunker sample here :
https://plnkr.co/edit/U25PdXhSwXhxqJeQXcM6?p=preview

Comment: Instead of refactoring the pieces of ng-dialog why not just add this to the ng-dialog domain $scope.emojiMessage={};